# Google Sheets App Script - Convert a function to an onEdit of a specific cell

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a function which sets a formula in a range of cells and then copies that formula down.
This seems to work fine.

I would like to convert this into an onEdit function which runs when cell D11 is edited on the current tab.

I have not had much luck so far.

```
function copyDownAll() {
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  ss.getRange("A12:C12").setFormula("=Master!A7");
  let noRows = ss.getMaxRows();
 
  let fillDownRange = ss.getRange(12,1,noRows+1,4);
  ss.getRange("A12:C12").copyTo(fillDownRange);
  
  let fillDownRange2 = ss.getRange(11,4,noRows+1,1);
  ss.getRange("D11").copyTo(fillDownRange2);
}
```

Comment: Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data, and showing your _hand-entered_ expected results there.

Answer (score 1):

After a bit more searching I found the following solution which seems to work so far

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if(e.range.getA1Notation() =='D11'){

  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  ss.getRange("A12:C12").setFormula("=Master!A7");
  let noRows = ss.getMaxRows();
 
  let fillDownRange = ss.getRange(12,1,noRows+1,4);
  ss.getRange("A12:C12").copyTo(fillDownRange);
  
  let fillDownRange2 = ss.getRange(11,4,noRows+1,1);
  ss.getRange("D11").copyTo(fillDownRange2);
  };
};
```

#### Reference:

- [getA1Notation()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getA1Notation())

Comment: The code gets the number of rows in the _edited_ sheet, so it may not copy all non-null values that appear in `Master!A7:C`. This method will work only as long as the hard-coded row and column numbers remain valid. There will be a performance hit when cell `D11` is edited, and the version history will show thousands of updates each time as well.

Comment: Thanks, I am quite new to app script.  I have a Master sheet with names and days on it.  Each day then has its own Day tab. I want the day tabs to update but not if I add a row or delete a row as I have static data aligned with the dynamic data and if a row is inserted and it updates automatically then it will be out of alignment.  I wanted a method where all day sheets in the past remain as is and day sheets in the future can be updated when a new row is added or deleted.  I realise I am not making much sense. But I appreciate that the onEdit is probably not the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Your comments suggest that you are exposed to the risk of [rows getting misaligned](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/95901649).

To avoid potential trouble going forward, you may want to explore putting *all* data in the Master sheet, and have everyone edit it there.

Use [filter views](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3540681) to let multiple simultaneous users edit the sheet without disturbing each other. Insert links in the frozen section to easily switch between filter views — see the [Filter views example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ME5b4J6fQa8RRainxGtQkwTKFCg96N8_k6kCe8ABNyk/edit#gid=2048818001&fvid=336145647) spreadsheet.

To answer your original question, this sort of thing is usually done in Google Sheets with an [arrayformula()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093275) or an [{ array expression }](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276). Try this in cell `A12`:

`={ Master!A7:C }`

This expression will fill columns `A:C` all the way down with values from `Master`.

Comment: Thank you but I need this to be an onEdit function as I want to update and refresh when I add a row on the Master sheet and when I edit cell D11

Comment: with your method I get a #REF! error when I delete a row.

Comment: With an array expression, the results are fully dynamic and always up-to-date. I do not think there is any source sheet transformation that could result in a `#REF!` except the complete deletion of columns `A:C`.

Comment: Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219).